# Why was the correct and accepted answer deleted?

Tags: support, answers

It seems there was a correct answer under [Movie about ability to touch objects and know its past](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/61678/movie-about-ability-to-touch-objects-and-know-its-past).

Since I can't see who wrote it, I hesitate to recreate it - after all is was user [John](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/41249/john) who came up with the solution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because it was no answer at all. All it was saying was

> Was it Jeff Goldblum in the movie Vibes (1988)?

That is in itself just a comment and thus was converted into one.

There is sometimes a bit of leeway with incomplete answers like this, where we encourage people to flesh it out more and first mark it as in need of improvement and scheduled for deletion later. But seeing how it was only phrased as a question anyway, that threshold wasn't reached there and it was deemed nothing but a comment.

If you or anyone else can flesh this comment out into something that doesn't just hesitatingly ask if it might be this movie and can provide some details to back up the answer, feel free to repost it.

For more information on the problem of incomplete answers to identification questions, see [this related discussion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1870/49).

Comment: I disagree.  I was an answer.  Also, it was THE answer. OK, I should have said "It was ..." as opposed to "Was it...". But that's what editing is for -- from other interested readers. I would have gladly welcomed someone to do that.

Comment: @John But even then it's not really much of an answer. As said, there's room for leeway in such cases, but all factors pointed to this being better suited as a comment.